# Colocar uma string corrida dentro da clausula IN do sql como se fosse um array

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql, apex

Olá, necessito colocar dentro de uma **cláusula IN do SQL** um item que é string e precisa ser tratado como se fosse um array de string, utilizo o Oracle apex.

Tenho um item de página por exemplo **:P10_CODIGO_PROJETO** que contem o valor **'PJ8674,PJ8804,PJ8480'**

Exemplo que eu tenho

```
SELECT * FROM PROJETOS WHERE CODIGO_PROJETO IN ('PJ8674,PJ8804,PJ8480')
```

porém o select acima me retorna no_data_found pois ele acha que o código do projeto é corrido mas o eq eu precisaria era que fosse como um IN mesmo

```
SELECT * FROM PROJETOS WHERE CODIGO_PROJETO IN ('PJ8674','PJ8804','PJ8480')
```

por acaso existe alguma função em PL/ SQL que possa me auxiliar neste problema?

objetivo

Answer (score 1):

Da pra fazer utilizando a função `INSTR` e alterando um pouco sua condição de pesquisa.

Exemplo:

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM PROJETOS 
 WHERE INSTR(',' ||'PJ8674,PJ8804,PJ8480' || ',',  ',' || CODIGO_PROJETO || ',') > 0
```

Veja este exemplo rodando [aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9a2f4b/2).

Essa condição representa o seguinte:
Procure por: `,PJ8674,`
Dentro desse texto: `,PJ8674,PJ8804,PJ8480,`.

Alguns contras:

- Não funciona caso o tamanho do parâmetro ultrapasse 4000 bytes.
- Não irá funcionar corretamente se os valores da coluna não forem uma chave.
- Se torna lento quando há muitos códigos dentro do mesmo parâmetro.

Comment: Cara muito obrigado era exatamente disso que eu precisava, e com relação a performance serão no máximo de 4 a 5 por vez pois minha empresa trabalha com no máximo 5 por departamento por mês e foi basicamente instantâneo o procedimento completo que eu precisava fazer!!

Comment: Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Se a resposta realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Comment: Nas versões mais atuais o Oracle tem uma solução para isto , eu tenho uma solução publicada , não achei , que faz um CAST da STRING para uma tabela e fica algo como and exists (select....) depois eu tento localizar as duas.

Comment: https://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/parametro-para-sql-com-mais-de-um-valor/322419 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57923777/how-to-use-object-type-data-for-a-in-clause-in-oracle-sql    não localizei a solução padrão

Comment: @Motta da pra fazer [assim](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9a2f4b/4) também.

Comment: regexp_substr é uma coisa que domino pouco , mas sei que ajuda muito.